# jQuery onclick="AddOrRemoveClass(whateverClass)"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to make this work.

I want to add a class to the first child by clicking on the father element (using `onclick="AddOrRemoveClass(whateverClass)"` on the html, so I can use it with different classes in different elements).

Can someone give me some help? :D

```js
  function AddOrRemoveClass(thisClass) {
    class = `.${thisClass}`;
    child = this.children[0];
    if ($(child).hasClass(class)) {
    $(child).removeClass(class);
    } else {
        $(child).addClass(class);
    }
  }
```

```css
    .red {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      background: red;
      width:200px;
      height:80px;
    }
    .blue {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background: blue;
      width: 200px;
      height: 80px;
      left: 200px;
    }
    .green {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      background: green;
      width:200px;
      height:80px;
    }
    .purple {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background: purple;
      width:200px;
      height:80px;
      left: 200px;
    }
    .ib {
      display: inlineblock;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  
</head>
<body>

  <div class="red" onclick="AddOrRemoveClass(ib)">
    <div class"blue">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="green" onclick="AddOrRemoveClass(ib)">
    <div class"purple">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's value of the variable `ib`?   Or did you mean `onclick="AddOrRemoveClass('ib')"`?

Comment: Also see [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) rather than "if then remove else add" as it does that for you

Comment: And... `.` is for *selectors* - when you use `addClass` or `hasClass` you want it without the "." - eg `$(child).removeClass(thisClass);` - you have no need for `"."+thisClass` in your code.

Comment: Well, I tried, but maybe I misunderstood you. I'll leave below the changes that I think you suggested.

Comment: You'll notice an error when you try to run your code. `class` is a reserved word, so you can't use that as a variable name.  Next you can't use `this` in an onclick handler, you have to pass it in : `onclick="AddOrRemoveClass(this, 'ib')"` and `function AddOrRemoveClass(el, thisClass)`.  Then your `<div class"blue">` / purple are missing `=` `<div class="blue">`